# Modifying ruby code to work with Postgresql

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sqlite, pg

I was previously using sqlite3 for my ruby code and it worked fine for the following code

```
def existsCheck( db, id )
    temp = db.exec( 'SELECT 1 WHERE EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM Products
        WHERE promoID = ?
    ) ', [id] ).length > 0
end


def writeDB( db, product )
    db.exec( 'INSERT INTO Products ( promoID, name, price, shipping, condition, grade, included, not_included, image, time_added )
                        VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', [product.promoID, product.name, product.price, product.shipping, product.condition, product.grade, product.included, product.notIncluded, product.image, product.time] )
end
```

Does Postgresql not support the idea of "?" or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Don't write directly to the gem/driver for a database, instead use an ORM like [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/). In particular, read through the [Cheat Sheet](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/cheat_sheet_rdoc.html). Sequel works extremely well with PostgreSQL; The author is a big fan of that DBM. The benefit to using an ORM is you don't have to write SQL specific for the database, you let the ORM do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [fine `PG::Connection` manual](http://rubydoc.info/gems/pg/PG/Connection%3aexec):

> `- (PG::Result) exec(sql[, params, result_format ])`
>   `- (Object) exec(sql[, params, result_format ]) {|pg_result| ... }`
>   [...]
>   PostgreSQL bind parameters are represented as `$1`, `$1`, `$2`, etc., inside the SQL query. The 0th element of the params array is bound to `$1`, the 1st element is bound to `$2`, etc. `nil` is treated as `NULL`.

So you want to use numbered placeholders with PostgreSQL:

```
def existsCheck( db, id )
    temp = db.exec( 'SELECT 1 WHERE EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM Products
        WHERE promoID = $1
    ) ', [id] ).to_a.length > 0
    # You'll also need to .to_a the result before you can
    # treat it as an array...
end
```

Comment: Maybe `SELECT 1 FROM Products WHERE promoID = $1 LIMIT 1` will be better. Instead of the odd `SELECT 1 WHERE EXISTS ...`

Comment: @Igor: I think it is a variant of the more common `select exists (select 1 from ...)` construct which, AFAIK, some databases have special optimizations for.

Comment: `SELECT EXIST (...)` and `SELECT 1 ... LIMIT 1` will take equal time in PostgreSQL. But `SELECT ... LIMIT 1` is way easier to write and understand. Yet `SELECT EXIST` may be relevant if the project is for multiple databases.